# $\cos(105°)$ using sum and difference identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was trying to solve $\cos(105°)$ using sum and difference identities.

My solution:

$\cos(105°) = \cos(60°+45°)$
$\cos(60°)\cos(45°) - \sin(60°)\sin(45°)$
so,

$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ - $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

then,

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}$

last,

$\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}}{4}$

but when I try to use calculator it says,

$\frac{-\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$

What part of the solution I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to obtain $\cos 45$ or $\cos 105$? Your title says one thing, but your post body says another.

Comment: Also, your last two expressions are the same: $a-b = -b+a$.

Comment: What difference do you see between $\sqrt 2 -\sqrt 6$ and $-\sqrt 6+\sqrt 2$?

Comment: "what part of the solution I am doing it wrong?"  Not noticing that $\frac {\sqrt 2 -\sqrt 6}4 = \frac {-\sqrt 6 + 2}4$ and that you and the calculator both have the exact same solution and you have done it 100% correctly.  That's your only mistake.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this because of "lack of focus", can they explain why they made this assessment? It seems perfectly well focused to me.

Comment: Please say " 105 degrees." The sin and cos functions, interpreted geometrically, assume an angle measured in radians.

Comment: You are correct; if you use a calculator that displays solutions in mathematically set notation, your calculator displayed the answer with increasing numbers, showing the $-\sqrt {6}$ first, then $\sqrt {2}$ before putting it over the denominator $4$.  (See also Brian Tung's reasoning.)

Comment: @PrimeMover Perhaps the OP did not focus enough on the two expressions to see that they are the same. :) (I did not vote to close.)

Comment: @Gary that would be a dangerous precedent: "I voted to close because OP should have been able to answer it him/herself." Where do you draw the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a - b = a + (-b) = (-b) + a = -b + a$.
Thus,
$$\frac{\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{6}}{4} = \frac{-\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}}{4}$$
and both your answers are correct (they are equivalent).